# How do I have multiple posts on the same page so I can query the same table depending on each post?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a page on my website that lists all of the information from my MySQL database and displays it in an html table. Above my html table I have another html table with buttons and and a dropdown with checkboxes that I use to filter the table with my database info inside of it. All of my filter work individually but when i try to make them work together the page reloads and it only displays the filtered information from the most recently pressed filter. is there anyway to make all of the post methods work together?

heres an example of how i would like it to work:

```
(this parts a 
dropdown menu)
[x]loop               rooftop       happy hour
[ ]river north       [yes] [no]     [yes] [no]
[ ]old town
[x]river west
[ ]west loop
[submit]
```

on submit all of the checkboxes are posted. This part works but if i click yes for rooftop only the info for rooftop appear and it seems like the checkboxes become unchecked.

```
// my filter table
    <form method="POST">
        <table id="filter">
            <div id="title"> <h4> Filters </h4></div>
            <tr>
                <th> <h4> Rooftop </h4> </th>
                <th> <h4> Area </h4> </th>
                <th> <h4> Happy Hour </h4> </th>
                <th> <h4> Food </h4> </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="rooftop" value="Yes" class="editbtn"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="noRooftop" value="No" class="editbtn"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="sortBy">
                        <button onclick="dropDown()" type="button" class="dropbtn"> ‿ </button>
                        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                        <div id="area">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" id="loop" name="loop" value="Loop">Loop<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" id="Old Town" name="oldTown" value="Old Town"> Old Town <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" id="River North" name="riverNorth" value="River North"> River North <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" id="River West" name="riverWest" value="River West"> River West <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" id="West Loop" name="westLoop" value="West Loop"> West Loop <br>
                            <input id="areaSubmit" type="submit" value="Search" onclick("submitArea()")>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="happyHour" value="Yes" class="editbtn"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="noHappyHour" value="No" class="editbtn"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="food" value="Yes" class="editbtn"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="noFood" value="No" class="editbtn"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

// my php that filters the info
<?php
        require_once("database_connection.php");
        $db = db_connect();

        $loop = $_POST["loop"];
        $oldTown = $_POST["oldTown"];
        $riverNorth = $_POST["riverNorth"];
        $riverWest = $_POST["riverWest"];
        $westLoop = $_POST["westLoop"];
        $rooftop = $_POST["rooftop"];
        $noRooftop = $_POST["noRooftop"];
        $happyHour = $_POST["happyHour"];
        $noHappyHour = $_POST["noHappyHour"];
        $food = $_POST["food"];
        $noFood = $_POST["noFood"];
        $sql = "SELECT bar_name, area, hourStart, hourEnd FROM barInfo WHERE visible = 1";
        if(isset($loop)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR area = 'Loop'";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND area = 'Loop'";
            }
        }
        if(isset($oldTown)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR area = 'Old Town'";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND area = 'Old Town'";
            }        }
        if(isset($riverNorth)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR area = 'River North'";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND area = 'River North'";
            }
        }
        if(isset($riverWest)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR area = 'River West'";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND area = 'River West'";
            }
        }
        if(isset($westLoop)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR area = 'West Loop'";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND area = 'West Loop'";
            }
        }

        if(isset($rooftop)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR rooftop = 1";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND rooftop = 1";
            }
        }

        if(isset($noRooftop)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR rooftop = 0";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND rooftop = 0";
            }
        }

        if(isset($happyHour)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR area = 'Loop'";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND area = 'Loop'";
            }
        }
        if(isset($noHappyHour)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR happyHour = 0";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND happyHour = 0";
            }
        }
        if(isset($food)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR food = 1";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND food = 1";
            }
        }
        if(isset($noFood)) {
            $sqlArr = explode(" ", $sql);
            $count = 0;
            foreach($sqlArr as $word){
                if ($word == "AND"){
                    $count += 1;
                }
            }
            if($count > 0){
                $sql .= " OR food = 0";
            }
            else{
                $sql .= " AND food = 0";
            }
        }




        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
?>




// how i post the info as a html table

<?php
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "<table id='list'><tr><th><h3>Name</h3></th><th><h3> Area</h3></th><th><h3>Happy Hour Times</h3></th></tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<tr> <th> <h6> " . $row["bar_name"] . "</h6> </th> <th> <h6>" . $row["area"] . "</h6> </th> <th> <h6>" . $row["hourStart"] . "-" . $row["hourEnd"] . "</h6> </th> </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table";
    }
?>
```

Any help or resources are appreciated Thank You!

Comment: Do you get all the values on the form when one of the many submits occur? I'd start by changing `input type="submit"` to `input type="radio"`. Use JavaScript to Xhr (ajax) submit the entire form on changes. Consider doing a GET instead of a POST. Makes it 'portable' I can send you an email with link to the same data, filters and all - easier to test too.

Comment: i get the values but they get reset when i click on a different button

Answer (score 0):

first of, we would need dont see your submitArea function..

I did modify, simplify and secured a little bit (not everything but still..) your code, note that i did not test it..

1)
In your HTML, remove your `.editBtn` submit buttons. For Yes/No selection i suggest you use some `<select>` dropdowns or `<input type="radio">` buttons.

```
<form>
    <table id="filter">
        <div id="title"> <h4> Filters </h4></div>
        <tr>
            <th> <h4> Rooftop </h4> </th>
            <th> <h4> Area </h4> </th>
            <th> <h4> Happy Hour </h4> </th>
            <th> <h4> Food </h4> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="rooftop" class="selectMenu">
                    <option value="">Select an option</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="sortBy">
                    <button onclick="dropDown()" type="button" class="dropbtn"> ‿ </button>
                    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <div id="area">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" id="loop" name="loop" value="Loop">Loop<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" id="Old Town" name="oldTown" value="Old Town"> Old Town <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" id="River North" name="riverNorth" value="River North"> River North <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" id="River West" name="riverWest" value="River West"> River West <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" id="West Loop" name="westLoop" value="West Loop"> West Loop <br>
                        <input id="areaSubmit" type="submit" value="Search" onclick("submitArea()")>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <select id="happyHour" class="selectMenu">
                    <option value="">Select an option</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="food" class="selectMenu">
                    <option value="">Select an option</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

2)
Send your areas in an array instead of one by one, this makes it a lot easier to loop and build your query, here is a simple remake of your submitArea() function using jQuery.

```
<script>
    function submitArea() {
        var post_vals = {
            params: {
                areas: [],
                rooftop: 0,
                happyHour: 0,
                food: 0
            }
        };
        $(".get_value checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            post_vals.params.areas.push($(this).val());
        });
        $(".selectMenu option:selected").each(function() {
            if($(this).attr("id") == "rooftop") {
                post_vals.params.rooftop = 1;
            } else if($(this).attr("id") == "happyHour") {
                post_vals.params.happyHour = 1;
            } else if($(this).attr("id") == "food") {
                post_vals.params.food = 1;
            }
        });
        alert("Check your console for posted value!");
        console.log("Post values:");
        console.log(post_vals);
        $.getJSON("your_php_script.php", {
            params: params
        }).done(function(data) {
            // For now if you look in the console, you'll only see your query..
            alert("Post finished, check the response in your console.");
            console.log(data);
            // Get your data here and do what ever you want with it, IE: rebuild your table rows if they're not already existing.
        });
    }
</script>
```

3)
Simplify your PHP and be more SECURE with SQL injections, read about this on google or this site. For the example i called it your_php_script.php ;)

```
<?php
require_once("database_connection.php");
$connection = db_connect();

$response = array(
    "status" => "success",
    "data" => array(), // Table data goes in here
    "query" => "" // Temporairy, just for your example to show in your Javascript console
);

if(isset($_GET["params"]) && is_array($_GET["params"])) {

    // Prepare mysql statement
    $sql = "SELECT bar_name, area, hourStart, hourEnd FROM barInfo WHERE visible = 1";

    // Loop over the sent parameters
    foreach($_GET["params"] AS $key => $opt) {
        if($key == "areas") {
            if(is_array($opt)) {
                // HERE Beware that you should check the values before you put them in the query for injections security reasons.
                foreach($opt AS $k => $area) {
                    // Real basic method of doing it.. be aware that this is not bullet proof.
                    $opt[$k] = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $area);
                }
                $sql .= " AND area IN ('" . implode("', '", $opt) . "') ";
            }
        } else if($key == "rooftop") {
            if($opt == 1) {
                $sql .= " AND rooftop = 1 ";
            } else {
                $sql .= " AND rooftop = 0 ";
            }
        } else if($key == "happyHour") {
            if($opt == 1) {
                $sql .= " AND happyHour = 1 ";
            } else {
                $sql .= " AND happyHour = 0 ";
            }
        } else if($key == "food") {
            if($opt == 1) {
                $sql .= " AND food = 1 ";
            } else {
                $sql .= " AND food = 0 ";
            }
        }
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if($result) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $response["data"][] = $row;
        }
        // Temporairy
        $response["query"] = $sql;
    } else {
        $response["status"] = "error";
        $response["details"] = "MySQL Query error: " . mysqli_error($connection);
    }

} else {
    $response["status"] = "error";
    $response["details"] = "Parameter received is not an array.";
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

I hope this help.

Comment: "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in" I get this error when i try your code. I updated the code i have to show you where the error occurs. "if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {" Do you know why it would say $result is null?

Comment: Hmm I didnt use mysqli_num_rows in the answer.. did i?

Comment: no but it is how i show the information from the query

Comment: I think i know why, you're not using $connection anywhere.. change $db to $connection and it should work. Also please note that you should check for mysql connection before continue.

Comment: Edited my answer in the php section.

Answer (score -1):

You could limit the results by an order to order them by the last ones and then the previous ones. W3Schools ref: [W3Schools SQL - Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)